# net user command across entire directory

Tags: active-directory, domaincontroller

I come across net user command to check the user part of which AD group.
I wonder is there any similar command in CMD/PS to check the user part of which AD group across the entire directory.
Under dsa.msc utility we can search the user across entire directory, is there any similar way in CMD that can show the user across different domain controller and the corresponding AD group user is part of.

Thanks in Advance
Prashanth

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're just looking for a command, this is the wrong place. If you need help with a batch file: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The "Entire Directory" searches the Global Catalog (GC), which allows you to search the entire AD forest.

But if you are only looking at one user, then that won't help you any. You can find all the groups that a user is a member of without the GC by looking at the `memberOf` attribute.

In PowerShell you can do this with [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adprincipalgroupmembership), like this:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership UserName
```